# Retrieving Terminal Services Session ID In .NET?

Tags: .net, terminal-services, sessionid

Can anyone please help me discover the .NET equivalent of the following C++ code:

```
DWORD session_id;
ProcessIdToSessionId(GetCurrentProcessId(), &session_id);
```

I'm trying to find the current terminal services session number to uniquely name a named pipe that two programs inside the same session are using to communicate with each other. But the only information I can find when searching for .NET sessions is web stuff.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Indeed, this functionality is provided completely within the BCL (`System.Diagnostics` namespace):

```
var sessionId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().SessionId;
```

See the [`SessionId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.sessionid.aspx) property on MSDN for more info.